# A Strange effect on iPhone6 and iPhone6+ when I Swipe Left-to-Right and Right-to-Left on Home button twice

Tags: iphone

Here is image of that strange effect.[image: A Strange Effect]

Is **Apple** is going to implement some new feature or a bug.?

Comment: It's for people who only use their thumbs, so they can still reach the top of the screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a feature designed to bring the top of your screen into reach when you are using these new larger devices with one hand.  It's actually activated by a double tap (not press) on the home button.

Check out the item "Reachability" on this apple page:
https://www.apple.com/iphone-6/tips/